# Command to open port and read data

Tags: scripts

What terminal command can I use to open a port (say 80), accept an incoming connection and print received data? I have a script that runs on unknown remote machine and I want it to report back to me, at at least check if it has connectivity. Can I use netcat `nc`?

Comment: Sure you can. `sudo nc -l 80` (since ports < 1024 need root)

Comment: Great, make it an answer?